# Java - method that returns a class instance to different class?

Tags: java, class, object, methods, instance

I'm a beginner and have tried searching but nothing is coming up, apologies. I have 2 classes, I don't know how to link the rewardCoins (oneCoin/twoCoin/threeCoin) so that if called, it adds coins to the Bag inventory. The return is probably incorrect as well.

```
public class Bag {
    private int oneCoin;
    private int twoCoin;
    private int threeCoin;
    
    //etc
}

public class Thief {
     public Thief(String name, int level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = level * 100;
        this.level = level;
    }
    
    //problem code
    public Bag rewardCoins(){
        oneCoin =+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/6);
        twoCoin =+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/2);
        threeCoin =+ (int)((level-level/2)-Math.random()*(level-level/2));
        return rewardCoins();
    }
}
```

Not looking for immediate help, I just don't know what I should be reading up on to figure it out.

Edit: I may have explained it poorly - I can't use setters, as there are already things inside the Bag inventory. I want to add the coins to the inventory when a Thief is "defeated". Like dropping loot. I don't know how to access the private fields one/two/threeCoin in Thief to add them to the other class. They are 2 different classes, Thief.java and Bag.java

Second edit: for anyone reading this, the answer is changing the attributes and return value to-

```
public Bag rewardCoins(){
        int one = (int)(level-Math.random()*level/6);
        int two = (int)(level-Math.random()*level/2);
        int three = (int)((level-level/2)-Math.random()*(level-level/2));
        return (new Bag(one, two, three));
}
```

Comment: You need an instance of `Bag` in `Thief`, declared like any other variable (like `name` or `health` in your code), then you need to initialize it (likely in the constructor), then you'll need `Bag` to provide accessor methods (getter and setters) to `oneCoin`, `twoCoin` and `threeCoin`.

Comment: your Function `rewardCoins()` is a recursive function with no exit condition.

Comment: I assume your Thief is supposed to have a Bag? If so, Thief needs a field of type Bag.

Comment: Also instead of `=+` you probably want `+=`

Comment: Thank you for the replies, they are not exactly what I was confused with. Have updated my question

Answer (score 0):

You may want something like this:

```
public class Thief {
    private final String name;
    private final int health;
    private final int level;

    public Thief(String name, int level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = level * 100;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Bag rewardCoins(Bag bag){
        int oneCoin = bag.getOneCoin();
        int twoCoin = bag.getTwoCoin();
        int threeCoin = bag.getThreeCoin();

        oneCoin =+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/6);
        twoCoin =+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/2);
        threeCoin =+ (int)((level-level/2)-Math.random()*(level-level/2));

        Bag result = new Bag();
        result.setOneCoin(oneCoin);
        result.setTwoCoin(twoCoin);
        result.setThreeCoin(threeCoin);

        return result;
    }
}
```

or this:

```
public class Thief {
    private final String name;
    private final int health;
    private final int level;
    private Bag bag;

    public Thief(String name, int level) {
        this.name = name;
        this.health = level * 100;
        this.level = level;
    }

    public Bag rewardCoins(){
        int oneCoin = bag.getOneCoin();
        int twoCoin = bag.getTwoCoin();
        int threeCoin = bag.getThreeCoin();

        oneCoin =+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/6);
        twoCoin =+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/2);
        threeCoin =+ (int)((level-level/2)-Math.random()*(level-level/2));

        Bag result = new Bag();
        result.setOneCoin(oneCoin);
        result.setTwoCoin(twoCoin);
        result.setThreeCoin(threeCoin);

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends.
Looking at your code I can suppose that you want the thief to reward coins to the inventory which is shared among thieves. In that case you could have it as a variable of the thief and pass it as a parameter on the constructor. This way all thieves will be able to access the same Bag object.

```
public class Bag {
private int oneCoin;
private int twoCoin;
private int threeCoin;

//getters and setters
}

public class Thief {
private Bag bag;
 public Thief(String name, int level,final Bag bag) {
    this.name = name;
    this.health = level * 100;
    this.level = level;
    this.bag=bag;
}


public void rewardOneCoin(){

    bag.setOneCoin(bag.getOneCoin()+ (int)(level-Math.random()*level/6))
   
    
}

// Appropriate functions for two and three coins
}
```

If you can give me a bit more context I may cal provide you with a bit more help

Comment: @egtc To access the variables in the way that you mention you will have to move your functions to the bag class and when the thief is defeated invoke them from the object you have instansiated